# Running programs/apps

Tags: python-2.7

How do I run/start python after downloading?  I am new to both Linux and Ubuntu so I need some pointers.  I have been MS for so long I think it has brain washed me!

Comment: How did you run it in Windows? Using [IDLE](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Idle_gui.png)? Usually to run a python program you run `python /path/to/script.py` in a terminal, but there are many other options.

Comment: it depends, what app did you download? how did you download it (pip or direct download)? please be specific

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by terminal (simply type `python` + path to your file eg. `~/Desktop/Test.py` ).

You can start terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` or by launcher icon in upper left corner of your screen.